# What if one peer is down

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Let's say we have a 6 peer in Hyperledger Fabric network and 3 organization. Each organization has 2 peers. All 6 peers belongs to one single channel.

What if one of the peer is down? Is the network still validate transaction and creates block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the way your chaincode is set up. On a channel you have chaincode deployed, this chaincode has a specific version number. When you instantiate the chaincode or when you upgrade it, you can specify which endorsement policy to use.

This endorsement policy dictates what rules a transaction must satisfy in order to be validated. To be more specific, it specifies the organisations who must endorse it, via their endorsing peers, of course.

You can read more about it here: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/endorsement-policies.html

If one of your orgs has 2 endorsing peers and the endorsement policy requires one peer, then if one goes down, you're still fine.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiDragotoniu